# Não consigo gravar os dados no meu firebase

Tags: ionic, firebase

> ```
> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
> Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
> ```

Configuração do meu firebase está assim:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if 'true';
    }
  }
}
```

Antes estava assim na configuração original:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: E porque você está fazendo `allow read, write: if 'true';` ao invés de deixar como estava antes `aallow read, write;`? Esse comando `if 'true';` não está funcionado pelo jeito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece que você está alterando os dados no local errado.

No *Firebase* há uma nova opção chamada *Cloud Firestore*, a qual vem selecionada por padrão(vide imagem abaixo), porém **Não é lá que deve alterar** e sim no *Realtime Database*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao selecionar a opção ***Realtime DataBase*>Regras**, altere as configurações para o seguinte:

```
{
  "rules": 
{
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, mano, você me salvou. Se tivesse jeito eu te dava um beijo na testa :)

Comment: Melhor jeito de retribuir é marcando a resposta como aceita ;) Veja: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079)

Comment: feito mano, valeu

Answer (score 0):

De uma olhada [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started?authuser=0)... O site do firebase possui uma ótima documentação, leia ela atentamente que você conseguirá fazer o que quer.

De acordo com este link você tem que fazer assim

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Sem as aspas que você colocou em `if 'true';`

E pelo que entendi você quer liberar o acesso para todos, então nesse caso deixe como já vem por padrão

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Então, quando fiz o teste, também tentei na configuração padrão e deu erro mesmo assim, ou talvez o erro acontece por que não tem usuário logado

Comment: Vai em Authentication > Método de login e habilitada o modo Anônimo e ve se resolve. E também tente o seguinte: Vá em Database > Cloud Firestore > Regras e use o simulador que tem lá